# How to undecorate JFrame while using jtattoo

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, uimanager

Although a similar question has been asked once before ([how to make frame undecorated after jTattoo theme installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341856/how-to-make-frame-undecorated-after-jtattoo-theme-installed)), but I'm unable to follow the solution to solve the problem. I didn't find the instruction is clear enough and hence failed  many tries.

I want an undecorated JFrame (and not only on fullscreen mode), but using any of the jtattoo themes unable me to do so.

Is there any way I can get my JFrame to be undecorated while using a jtattoo theme?

Comment: Might be out of date, but maybe [some of this](http://www.jtattoo.net/ThemeProps.html) might help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `java.util.Properties` as follows.
before initializing your window:

```
try{
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("windowDecoration", "on");
  <your lookandfeel>.setCurrentTheme(props);                         
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(<your lookandfeel>);
}catch(Exception e){...}
```

You can for example use `McWinLookAndFeel` or `AluminiumLookAndFeel` as your lookandfeel, it is not specified in your example.
Decorated (property on):
[image]
Undecorated (property off):
[image]