# How to set undecorated JTattoo look-and-feel JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel, uimanager

How to set undecorated JTattoo used `JFrame`?

I've tried this, but it does not work.

```
undecorated(true);
```

- [how to make frame undecorated after jTattoo theme installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38341856/9006622) this is a same question and not clear answer.
- [How to undecorate JFrame while using jtattoo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43034911/9006622) this one same too and no answers.

Comment: The answer in linked question seems clear to me: call `DecorationHelper.decorateWindows(false);` before `this.undecorated(true);` Is there any issue with it?

Answer (score 3):

Here I make something using java's `Property` class not only undecorated but also window title font and other properties like this

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("windowTitleFont", "Ebrima PLAIN 15");
p.put("logoString", "");
p.put("windowDecoration", "off");
HiFiLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(p);
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works for me
Just code setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false) inside the main method

Ex -

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
}
});
```